# Ubuntu WebServer in HyperV

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, hyper-v

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2, with HyperV running Ubuntu 15.10 Server. The problem im having is something to do with networking and routing.

I can never connect to both the Windows Server and the Ubuntu Server at the same time. It interchanges. If i can connect to the Ubuntu Server through SSH, i can't RDP into the Windows Server, or i can't connect to the SSH server on the Windows Server. I only have one internet connected network device.

Current setup is i have a 1 IPv4 Address. The Windows Server is setup using that, and i've also got the Ubuntu Server running off that. Not sure if i should have the Ubuntu Server server running off a different IPv4 address? Or should i set it to be running an internal IPv4 address?

What i want is to be able to setup a webserver on Ubuntu, and run some websites. I've done this, but i can't seem to get traffic to point towards the Ubuntu Web Server. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and include as many details as you can about your networking configuration.

Comment: Done, hopefully that helps

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the same IP address for both operating systems. You will either need to get a second IP or set up a NAT network and port forward from your host's IP to your guest's IP.